# How to catch a SocketException

Tags: sockets, f#, try-with

I am having trouble constructing the `with` portion of the following F# `try..with` statement. There are lots of exception handling examples out there, but I could not find any specifically matching the `SocketException` returned from `Dns.GetHostEntry` when the host does not exist. I am going to keep looking, but would appreciate a pointer.

```
let test_smtp (smtp_server_address : string) (port : int) =
    let expectedResultCode = 220
    let hostEntry : IPHostEntry =  
        try 
            Dns.GetHostEntry(smtp_server_address)
        with
            | :? System.Net.Sockets.SocketException -> printfn "GetHostEntry threw an exception "

    let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (hostEntry.AddressList.[0], port)
    ( use tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) 
      tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint)

      let temp_result = check_response tcpSocket expectedResultCode 
      temp_result
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is good so far; you just need to add the `as (name)` syntax to give a name to the exception object, then the `when (test)` syntax to test that a certain condition holds. E.g.,:

```
try 
  Dns.GetHostEntry(smtp_server_address)
with
  | :? System.Net.Sockets.SocketException as ex when ex.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.HostNotFound ->
    failwith "Host not found"
```

(NOTE: My original code tested `SocketErrorCode` against an int, because I misread the MSDN documentation. But [`SocketErrorCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.socketerrorcode(v=vs.110).aspx) is a [`System.Net.Sockets.SocketError` enum value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror(v=vs.110).aspx).)

One comment about your code: you don't need those parentheses around the `use tcpSocket = ...` expression. You can just write it inline with the rest of the code, and F# will dispose of the `tcpSocket` value when it goes out of scope at the end of the function:

```
let test_smtp (smtp_server_address : string) (port : int) =
    let expectedResultCode = 220
    let hostEntry : IPHostEntry =  
        try 
            Dns.GetHostEntry(smtp_server_address)
        with
            | :? System.Net.Sockets.SocketException as ex when ex.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.HostNotFound ->
                failwith "GetHostEntry threw an exception "

    let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (hostEntry.AddressList.[0], port)
    use tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) 
    tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint)

    check_response tcpSocket expectedResultCode
```

Comment: After the fix, a second error has occurred.It complains about 11001 as well as the original error saying it should be an IPHostEntry.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - My original answer was wrong: `SocketErrorCode` is an enum. I've updated it. Let me see about that IPHostEntry thing.

Comment: ... And the `printfn` was wrong. `printfn` returns `()`, the `unit` type. But every branch of the `try...with` expression needs to either return the same type as `Dns.GetHostEntry`, or else throw an exception. So I updated my example to throw an exception, since there's no meaningful `IPHostEntry` that you can return. Unless you rewrite this function to use [railway-oriented programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) style, but that's a larger question.

Comment: You're right. All that is left is the complaint that we're assigning to an IPHostEntry but have an 'a * b' instead.

Comment: I'm going to have to re-write it, because I want the program to continue.

Comment: You could move the `try ... with` to wrap pretty much the whole function body, and handle several potential exceptions. Or rewrite it in railway-oriented style, as that's more functional anyway.

Comment: I don't know where the `'a * 'b` is coming from; I don't see any commas in the `try ... with`, so I don't know why it's creating a tuple. I suggest opening a new question to ask about that one, as this comment thread is getting a little long by now.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a solution, but a workaround. It gets around the problem of a host-not-found error without having to use [railway-oriented programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) mentioned in @rmunn 's answer. (And that's a great article, by the way.)

So `false` can be returned if `Dns.GetHostEntry` throws an exception or if `check_response` fails to get the correct response from `HELO`.

```
module net_utilF_mod

open System
open System.Text
open System.Threading
open System.Net
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.IO

type Smtp1() = 
    member this.X = "F#"

let send_data (socket : Socket) (data : string) =
    let dataArray : byte [] = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
    socket.Send(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length, SocketFlags.None)

let check_response (socket:Socket) expectedResultCode =
    while socket.Available = 0 do
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 100  

    let responseArray : byte [] = Array.zeroCreate 1024
    socket.Receive(responseArray, 0, socket.Available, SocketFlags.None) |> ignore
    let responseData : string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
    let responseCode : int = Convert.ToInt32(responseData.Substring(0,3))
    if responseCode = expectedResultCode then
        true
    else
        false

let test_smtp (smtp_server_address : string) (port : int) =
    let helo_msg = String.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName())
    let hostEntry : IPHostEntry =  
        try 
            Dns.GetHostEntry(smtp_server_address)
        with
            | :? System.Net.Sockets.SocketException as ex when ex.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.HostNotFound ->
                 let tempEntry : IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(@"localhost")
                 tempEntry

    let email_server_reachable =
        match hostEntry.HostName with
        | @"localhost" -> false
        | _ ->  true


    if false = email_server_reachable then
        false
    else
        let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (hostEntry.AddressList.[0], port)
        ( use tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) 
          tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint) |> ignore

          let temp_response = 
              if true = check_response tcpSocket  220 then
                send_data tcpSocket helo_msg  |> ignore
                check_response tcpSocket 250              
              else
                false

          temp_response 
        )
```

Comment: A quick stylistic comment: I find `if true = (boolean value)` to be much less readable than a simple `if (boolean value)`. Likewise, `if false = (boolean value)` is less readable than `if not (boolean value)`. That's a habit that many Javascript programmers fall into because of Javascript's non-strict typing, but it's unnecessary in F#, which has strict typing, so you can use the more-readable `if (boolean)`. And your `match` expression that sets the `email_server_reachable` could also be more readable as `let email_server_reachable = hostEntry.HostName <> "localhost"`. One line, easy to read.